How do I join columns when there are null cells
Hi I have a table where there are 4 columns that I need which are 'sell_currency', 'sell_amount', 'buy_currency' and 'buy_amount'. The currency columns are varchar while the amount are numbers, and what I want to achieve is to calculate the sum of the amount by its currency, so this is the sql that I use to get the results:
  select
    sell_currency,
    sum(sell_amount) as sell_amount
    null as buy_currency
    null as buy_amount
  from table1
  group by
    sell_currency
  union
  select
    null as sell_currency,
    null as sell_amount,
    buy_currency,
    sum(buy_amount) as buy_amount
  from table1
  group by
    buy_currency

And with the data from the table1:
SELL_CURRENCY   SELL_AMOUNT BUY_CURRENCY    BUY_AMOUNT
A               123         D               1
B               234         E               2
B               345         D               3
A               222         (null)          0
C               4444        (null)          0

And this is the result I get from the table:
SELL_CURRENCY   SELL_AMOUNT BUY_CURRENCY    BUY_AMOUNT
A               345         (null)          (null)
B               579         (null)          (null)
C               4444        (null)          (null)  
(null)          (null)      D               4
(null)          (null)      E               2

However I want to remove those nulls and able to combine the rows together to achieve this result shown below:
SELL_CURRENCY   SELL_AMOUNT BUY_CURRENCY    BUY_AMOUNT
A               345         D               4
B               579         E               2
C               4444        (null)          (null)  

What do I need to do in order to achieve the result?
And for more information, these 4 columns are updated frequently as well so it could be more than 3 or 2 unique currencies in the sell and buy.

First UNION ALL, then GROUP BY.

Please add the sample input data to your question

hi @jarlh I removed the sum() for both amounts and changed it to UNION ALL and wrapped the sql into another select from to by group by sell_currency and buy_currency, but the result is still the same.

@Jonas sorry Jonas I am still pretty new to posting in stack overflow, what do you mean by that?

There aren't many other data that are relevant to the this unfortunately (not even id), although the table does have a 'sort_order' column which is to order the table

Of course, there are other data. Your queries sum data, so the original data is very likely different. For example, for Currency A, your query returns a sum of 345 as sell amount. No one know whether the input data in your table is one row only with 345 or 100 rows with values of 3 or 4 or also rows with NULL values. Please don't misuse comments for discussions, but edit your question and add the missing information. Input data is ALWAYS needed, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This seems like an unnecessary complication of basic join operation. Could you please provide the contents of table1?

You don't want a union, but a join.
select currency, s.sell_amount, b.buy_amount
from
(
  select sell_currency as currency, sum(sell_amount) as sell_amount
  from table1
  group by sell_currency
) s
full outer join
(
  select buy_currency as currency, sum(buy_amount) as buy_amount
  from table1
  group by buy_currency
 ) b using (currency)
 order by currency;


Thank you, although this works out and show the total amount for the sell and buy for each currencies, how difficult is it to make it into four columns, where the currency is splitted into sell_currency and buy_currency?

In the result rows, the sell currency equals the buy currency, so why show it twice? But of course you can: select currency as sell_curr, s.sell_amount, currency as buy_curr, b.buy_amount ... . Or keep the original column names and use ON sell_currency = buy_currency instead of USING (currency).

Ah, I just noticed that my query does not produce the result you desire. You want to show rows with arbitrarily mixed currencies. Don't do this. SQL is about relations. But sell_currency A is not related to buy_currency D as your result suggests. If, in your GUI you want to have a list of sell currency amounts and a list of buy currency amounts, then select the two data sets separately and ideally use two grids for the display or if you think this necessary fill a single grid with the data top down.

I see, if that is the case then I shall do that. Thank you for giving me a detailed explanation!
